# Script popup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I wonder how I would do that for [the reveal plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) to work out instead of only when you click a link, this function when entering the page.

Comment: what are you trying to. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

OP,

I **think** you want to trigger a click event on page load. This plugin expects you to have an element in your markup that would match this:

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]')
```

So, that'd look like this:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="foo"></a>
```

If you have the plugin working properly when a clicking on the link, all you need to do is:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[data-reveal-id="foo"]').trigger('click');
});
```